# Surface area of produced by a family of curves

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

I am considering a family of curves indexed by $a\in \mathbb{R}$:

$$\vec{r}_a(t)=\bigg(\frac{2t}{t^2+(t+a)^2+1},\frac{2(t+a)}{t^2+(t+a)^2+1},\frac{t^2+(t+a)^2-1}{t^2+(t+a)^2+1}\bigg).$$
Note that for each $a$, $\vec{r}_a(t)$ is a circular arc on the unit sphere passing through the north pole.

> What is the surface area of the patch on the sphere enclosed by
> $\vec{r}_{a_1}(t)$ and $\vec{r}_{a_2}(t)$?

Assuming $a_2>a_1$, I thought the answer is given by

$$\int_{a_1}^{a_2}\int_{\mathbb{R}} ||\partial_t\vec{r}_a(t)||||\partial_a\vec{r}_a(t)|| dt da$$

I got the above formula by naively looking at the change of the curves with small increments $(a\to a+da)$ and $(t\to t+dt)$ and treating the patch that it covers as a square.

But I don't think this is the right answer. Note that

$$||\partial_t\vec{r}_a(t)||= \frac{2\sqrt{2}}{t^2+(t+a)^2+1}, \quad ||\partial_a\vec{r}_a(t)||= \frac{2}{t^2+(t+a)^2+1}$$

If we integrate over the entire range we should have the surface area of the unit sphere: $4\pi$. However, we get that

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{\mathbb{R}} ||\partial_t\vec{r}_a(t)||||\partial_a\vec{r}_a(t)|| dt da=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{4\sqrt{2}}{(t^2+(t+a)^2+1)^2} dt da=4\sqrt{2}\pi.$$

So, I am not sure what is the right answer.

Comment: You've essentially got a parameterization of the two sphere here, so your integrand is incorrect. You should be taking the norm of the cross product of those two derivatives, as that is the area element.